# how to do distributed tracing / tracking with application insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I'm using several resources in Azure, and the flow looks like this:

1. get file from sftp
2. enrich file with data from http call
3. put messages on a queue
4. process messages
5. make some external calls
6. deliver data

**How do we trace where a specific 'run' is in the above process?**

Can we simply create a guid and pass it into app insights?

Comment: All the flow are in one same azure function? and not clear about "where a specific 'run' is in the above process", can you explain it more clear?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a perfect scenario for [Distributed tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-tracing)!

There are two main methods of handling this data, using the [Transaction Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/transaction-diagnostics) view, or the [Application Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map) view. The former helps find perfomance issues on a per request basis, while the latter offers a topological view of the interaction between various systems.

Most of the dependencies are auto-collected by the Application Insights SDK, as it supports distributed tracing natively through dependency auto-collectors, but you can also use the [TrackDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) API to track them manually.

Coming to correlating telemetry, the guid that you suggested takes the form of `operation_Id`, that associates telemetry with the logical operation performed. To know more about how this works under the hood, please take a look at [Telemetry correlation in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation).

For additional reading, there is also a neat blog post [here](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/distributed-tracing-with-application-insights-with-java-talking-with-azure-functions-7e5bac358a2c) illustrating the same with an example.

Hope this helps!